# react native android crash in RN fetch

Tags: react-native

we are struggling with quite a vague crash being caught by Sentry. The stack trace (below) seems to suggest that it is coming from within react-native. I have done some investigating and I think the crash happens in `fetch` when there is no internet connection. However it is only happening occasionally.

```
Error: network
  at onUnhandled(node_modules/@sentry/react-native/dist/js/integrations/reactnativeerrorhandlers.js:85:57)
  at onUnhandled(node_modules/promise/setimmediate/rejection-tracking.js:73:25)
  at apply(native)
  at anonymous(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:213:35)
  at _callTimer(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:113:15)
  at callTimers(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/Timers/JSTimers.js:359:30)
  at apply(native)
  at __callFunction(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:428:32)
  at anonymous(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:113:43)
  at __guard(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:367:7)
  at callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue(node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:112:18)
```

The reason I suspect `fetch` is because if I do something like this:

```
    try {
      response = await fetch(url, {
        method,
        body,
        headers,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
```

Then open the app on android in dev mode with no internet, I get the stack trace below, which is remarkably similar to the one in Sentry

[Caught error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKLM7.jpg)

We have a number of libraries/SDKs in our app which are using `fetch` under the hood, however at this point it is pretty much impossible to figure out exactly where it is happening. I mostly wondered if anyone in the community has come across this before and figured out where it is coming from?